# how to hide back a hidden div which was shown after jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Guys I was trying to make a notification menu which dropdown on `click event`.I have make that with below code but I have a problem that I can't hide it back.I want to hide it by clicking on body and `div` itself.How can I do that?

My html part.

```
<li class="clicker" >
 <a>Notification</a> 
    <div class="display_noti">
     <ol>
       <span>This is it :D</span><br>
       <span>This is it :D</span><br>
       <span>This is it :D</span><br>
      </ol>
    </div>
</li>
```

My css part

```
.display_noti
 {
    width: 400px;
    height: fixed;
    display:none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 5px;
 }
```

My jquery part.

```
$('.clicker').on('click',function(){
 if($('.display_noti').css("display","none")){
    $('.display_noti').show();
 }

});
```

I am trying with this jquery code too but when I keep this code `show()` function doesn't work.

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
  $('.display_noti').css("display","none");
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// hide some divs when click on window
        var actionwindowclick = function(e){
            if (!$(".display_noti, .clicker").is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && $(".display_noti , .clicker").has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
                $(".display_noti").hide(); 
            }
        }

$(window).on('click',function(e){
  actionwindowclick (e);
  });
$('.clicker').on('click',function(){
  $(".display_noti").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5yaq6vo0/1/)

Comment: sir tnx for your help :) I was trying to make some thing like that.Now can you help me to make that div box not to hide if we click on itself?I'm sorry I said some thing itself too on my question but i was suppose to say hide if clicked on window but not to hide if click on div itself.

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg just change slideToggle();  with .show()

Comment: wow it worked perfect sir :) thanks again.I wanna know that all sir.What scripting language should I learn sir?

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg you can use this tutorials .. its very simple and helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810  .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

just make your js code as:

```
$('.clicker').on('click',function(){
   $('.display_noti').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jp42q7t8/5/

**Update:**
also, if you want you may consider change the cursor shape on the `li` element to show that it is clickable like this:

```
.clicker { cursor:pointer; }
```

**Update2:**
If you add this somehow you can make the `<div class="display_noti">` disappear when you click on it i don't know why though but it fixes it:

```
 $('.display_noti').on('click',function(){
     $(this).css({'background':'black'}); //same background color of the inner div
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  $('.display_noti').hide();


});


$('.clicker').on('click', function(e) {

  $('.display_noti').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();


});

$('.display_noti').click(function(e){

  e.stopPropagation();


});
```

```css
.display_noti {
  width: 400px;
  height: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clicker"> <a>Notification</a> 
  <div class="display_noti">
    <ol> <span>This is it :D</span>
      <br> <span>This is it :D</span>
      <br> <span>This is it :D</span>
      <br>
    </ol>
  </div>
</li>
```